# heroku CLIをインストールしているにもかかわらず、インストールを要求されます

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

rubyの勉強がてらherokuに触ろうとしています。

gem install herokuを実行し、
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction
からherokuに登録してheroku CLIをインストールしました。

herokuコマンドを実行すると
Install the Heroku CLI from http://cli.heroku.com
と表示されるだけで終了してしまいます。

スペックは以下の通りです。
OS:Windows7
Ruby:2.4.4
git:2.18.0
heroku:公式サイトから落とした最新のもの(バージョン不明)

ネット上で少し調べてみましたが、同様の症状は見つかっていません。
こちら、解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂きたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/45567/29288で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku`コマンドは昔はgemの形でインストールされていましたが、今は提供されていません。

```
gem uninstall heroku
```

でgem経由でインストールしたものを削除してから試して見てください。